# Subtract a number from database and multiply by 2% +0.30

Tags: php

Assuming I have stored in the database the following

```
withdraw fee = 2
```

then upon withdrawing money i want the user to pay 2% for withdrawal fees for any amount he/she is receiving. Given the code below, it only deducts $2 instead of deducting %2 of the balance.

In my code, `$postd_cashout` is the fees to pay,
balance is the user's balance

What change should I make to this line for this to work

```
$postd_cashout = substr(number_format($ir['balance'], 3, '.', ','), 0, -1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We use Markdown here, not BBCode.  I've fixed up *some* of the formatting of your question for you.  For formatting help, click the fat orange question mark on the right of the formatting toolbar.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the formatting..

Comment: I don't see anything in that code related to subtraction... or databases. Anyway, subtracting 2% is equivalent to multiplying by `0.98`. Maths question, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$postd_cashout = ($ir['balance']*(1.02));
```

This results in a gross withdrawal of the intended amount plus 2% of that amount. I am unclear if this is exactly what you are trying to achieve, however. The amount the withdrawee receives in hand would be represented in $ir['balance'] whereas the gross amount withdrawn is reflected in $postd_cashout.

optionally:

```
$withdrawalmultiplier = 1.02;
$postd_cashout = ($ir['balance']*($withdrawalmultiplier));
```

This allows you to change the fee amount anywhere it is referenced in the code as opposed to hardcoding a static number. the intial example is more clear, imho.

finally:

```
$fee = ($postd_cashout - $ir['balance'])
```

I suppose tracking the fee amount is useful for reporting a sum of fees paid or itemizing a receipt and it sounds like this is ultimately what you're wanting after re-reading the question a few times. If the fee amount is all you're after then the other answer fits more elegantly.

Comment: Would try that right way to see if it solves the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the balance by the withdrawal fee as a percentage

```
$fees = ($ir['balance'] * $withdrawal_fee / 100);
```

You can then utilise $fees in your calculation.

Don't use number_format before the calculation as you want to avoid the commas - that converts the value to a string.